# Active Directory Users and Computer Security Permissions do not 'Stick'

Tags: active-directory

Until recently everything was working fine.  I wrote a program that allows a user to manage another user, it changes the password and sets an expiration date on the target account.

In Active Directory Users and Computer, I have added the user that is to control the target account, in the security settings with '*Full Control*'.  Until recently, when I check to see if the user is still listed in the target account's security settings, they are no longer listed.  It seems to 'stick' for about 5 to 10 minutes before it removes itself.

I cannot figure out why the user keeps getting removed automatically from the security settings under the target account...

Comment: Is the user whose ACL you are trying to change a domain admin by chance?

Comment: They were part of a group that was protected.  I took them out of that group and set their 'adminCount' attribute to <not set>  It seems to be sticking now.  But, I don't understand how it worked for so many months and now it's resetting permissions.  I didn't notice any other changes.